# How to add a constant attribute in xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-1.0, xml-serialization

Sorry I'm new to this that is why I need your help.

**Problem:**
I need to add a **Type** attribute in the  nodes. A value of **Others** for the  nodes inside the for each and **Main** for the single  node outside. Currently even if I add the xsl:attribute, the attribute won't show at all. Am I missing something here? Sorry I this is a basic mistake.

**Current XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
    <xsl:template name="Clr" match="Color">
        <Clr>
            <xsl:for-each select="Variations/Variation">
                <Variation>
                    <xsl:attribute name="Type">Others</xsl:attribute>
                    <Shade>
                        <Cd>Name</Cd>
                        <Val></Val>
                    </Shade>
                    <Shade>
                        <Cd>Code</Cd>
                        <Val></Val>
                    </Shade>
                </Variation>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <Variation>
                <xsl:attribute name="Type">Main</xsl:attribute>
                <Shade>
                    <Cd>Name</Cd>
                    <Val></Val>
                </Shade>
                <Shade>
                    <Cd>Code</Cd>
                    <Val></Val>
                </Shade>
            </Variation>
        </Clr>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Current Output:**

```
<Clr>
    <Variation>
        <Shade>
            <Cd>Name</Cd>
            <Val>Light Red</Val>
        </Shade>
        <Shade>
            <Cd>Code</Cd>
            <Val>LR</Val>
        </Shade>
    </Variation>
    <Variation>
        <Shade>
            <Cd>Name</Cd>
            <Val>Dark Red</Val>
        </Shade>
        <Shade>
            <Cd>Code</Cd>
            <Val>DR</Val>
        </Shade>
    </Variation>
    <Variation>
        <Shade>
            <Cd>Name</Cd>
            <Val>Red</Val>
        </Shade>
        <Shade>
            <Cd>Code</Cd>
            <Val>R</Val>
        </Shade>
    </Variation>
</Clr>
```

**Expected:**

```
<Clr>
    <Variation Type="Others">
        <Shade>
            <Cd>Name</Cd>
            <Val>Light Red</Val>
        </Shade>
        <Shade>
            <Cd>Code</Cd>
            <Val>LR</Val>
        </Shade>
    </Variation>
    <Variation Type="Others">
        <Shade>
            <Cd>Name</Cd>
            <Val>Dark Red</Val>
        </Shade>
        <Shade>
            <Cd>Code</Cd>
            <Val>DR</Val>
        </Shade>
    </Variation>
    <Variation Type="Main">
        <Shade>
            <Cd>Name</Cd>
            <Val>Red</Val>
        </Shade>
        <Shade>
            <Cd>Code</Cd>
            <Val>R</Val>
        </Shade>
    </Variation>
</Clr>
```

Comment: Please show a [mcve] including the input.

Comment: A stylesheet not declaring the XSLT namespace can't work. And closing the start tag as `<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" />` a self-closing element means your code is not even well-formed.

Comment: @MartinHonnen sorry updated

Comment: So where is the input you process?